# How to get errorMessage from restSharp?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, restsharp

How can I make RestClient get errormessage "this is a exception !" if my api server has:

`throw new Exception("this is a exception !")`;?

Comment: and what have you tried so far? what currently happens if you call a method with such exception form restclient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

> Note that exceptions from Execute are not thrown but are available in the ErrorException property.

```
var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

if (response.ErrorException != null)
{
    const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.";
    var twilioException = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
    throw twilioException;
}
```

Note:

```
response.ErrorException
```

[RestSharp Recommended Usage](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage)